# Why does facebook not like this

Tags: php, facebook

Hi when I debug in facebook devopers with the following code

> ```
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
> xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
> xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
> <html>
> <meta property="fb:app_id" content="lotsnumbers" />
> <meta property="og:title" content="FOR SALE"/>
> <meta property="og:type" content="product"/>
> <meta property="og:url" content="www.website.com.au/php_test.php"/>
> <meta property="og:image" content="image.gif"
> <meta property="og:description" content="Stuff for sale" />
> ```

I get the following error

Object at URL 'http://www.website.com.au/php_test.php' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value 'www.website.com.au/php_test.php' for property 'og:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

Can someone please tell me why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if that's your exact code, you have an unclosed tag

Comment: What is the real url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a [scheme](http://ogp.me/#url) (`http://` or `https://`) on your `og:url`. Its seems that it is not parsed correctly when its missing:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.website.com.au/php_test.php" />
```

And fix this missing self closing:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="image.gif" />
```